# Should i include model.train() with Dropout in PytorchLightning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, data-science, pytorch-lightning

I was reading guide in which an author used model.train() in each epoch because of the DropOut layer (he didn't use Pytorch Lightning). The question is - should i include model.train() in my Pytorch Lightning Module and if so, how do i do it ? (Or it does it automatically ?)

The code is below

```
class MulticlassClassificationLIGHT(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,class_weights):
        super(MulticlassClassificationLIGHT, self).__init__()
        
        self.num_feature=35
        self.num_class=36
        
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(self.num_feature, 512)
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(512, 128)
        self.layer_3 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.layer_out = nn.Linear(64, self.num_class) 
        
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)

        self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights.to(device)) 



    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer_1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        
        x = self.layer_2(x)
        x = self.batchnorm2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        
        x = self.layer_3(x)
        x = self.batchnorm3(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        
        x = self.layer_out(x)
        
        return x

        
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch 
        logits = self.forward(x) 
        loss = self.loss(logits, y) 
        self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        return loss
```

And here is an example from guide

```
    for e in tqdm(range(1, EPOCHS+1)):
        train_epoch_loss = 0
        train_epoch_acc = 0
        model.train()
        for X_train_batch, y_train_batch in train_loader:
            X_train_batch, y_train_batch = X_train_batch.to(device), y_train_batch.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
```

I use Trainer for training. Here is it

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(   
    devices="auto",
    accelerator="auto",
    auto_lr_find=False,
    auto_scale_batch_size=True,
    fast_dev_run=False,

    num_sanity_val_steps=3,

    logger=logger,   
    min_epochs=EPOCHS,

    )
```

And how I use it

```
trainer.fit(model, data_module_classifier.train_dataloader(),data_module_classifier.val_dataloader() )
```

There is just no information in the documentation and solutions are only in usual Pytorch, but not in Pytorch Lightning

Comment: You don't need to do `model.train()` for each epoch, unless you are doing `model.eval()` or `model.train(mode=False)`. Please post the complete code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @nithish08, I added code, so there is no model.train or eval as you can see

And should I specify something more if I use Dropout ?

Comment: Lightning automatically takes care of enabling and disabling the eval mode based on the step. You do not need to worry about this. The advantage of lightning is to forget about these kind of boiler plat pieces of code as it is taken care of under the hood.

Comment: I second the comment from @Harshanand. You don't need to do `model.train()`. To get into more details on the Trainer, please go through this page - https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/trainer.html

Comment: @nithish08  Thank you for your answers. Really made it clear for me, cause I was confused because of the guide and thought that I should do something similar in Lightning

Comment: @Harshanand The loss might be miscalculated (training loss will be underestimated) for models including layers like Dropout, if the loss is calculated in train mode.